# Specflow how to implement AppDomain isolation with Nunit 3

Tags: appdomain, specflow, nunit-3.0

I have written automation tests in Specflow 2.0, nUnit 3.X, TeamCity and Visual Studio 2013. I am trying to run the tests in parallel but they are failing because the code uses static classes/object.

On the Specflow website the recommendation is to run thread safe tests (if architecture depends upon static state) using **PARALLEL EXECUTION WITH MEMORY (APPDOMAIN) ISOLATION**
http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Parallel-Execution/

But there is no information as to how to do this and even googling I couldn't find any relevant article.

I am really appreciate if anyone can help me understand how do we do this.

Thanks for your help,
Satty

Answer (score 0):

How to configure the isolation depends on the test runner you are using.
I am not 100% sure that NUnit does support appdomain isolation, but a good start to find out would be the Parallelizable attribute documentation: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute

AppDomain or Process separation is possible if you are using the SpecFlow+Runner (http://www.specflow.org/plus/).
Here is a blogpost of the different modes in the SpecFlow+Runner: https://the-engineers.net/2016/04/08/using-specflowrunners-parallelization-features/

---

Full Disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow+Runner

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I am able to run multiple threads but the problem is the tests are not thread safe which is what I am trying to achieve. Unfortunately specflow+ is paid and I would try to make this work without it if I can first.

Comment: As the maintainer of NUnit, I can tell you that NUnit's parallel execution does not support AppDomain isolation for the parallel tests, only for the test run itself. It is a good idea for a feature, but since .NET Core will not support creating app domains anytime soon, it will be lower on our priorities.

Comment: Hey @RobProuse, has something changed in the last 7 years? Is this feature now admitted for NUnit?

Comment: @JMFS .NET Core does not and will never support AppDomains, so we have not and will not add any additional AppDomain features to NUnit. All new work will be to make sure NUnit works great with the current versions of .NET.

Comment: For running tests in parallel, NUnit DOES now have the `FixtureLifeCycle` attribute that makes writing thread safe tests easy. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

That's the reason why you shouldn't be using static classes in your code
Code with static (is like globals) considered harmful and hard to test